Line number and negated search combination in sed
I have a CSV whose tail is missing column data, e.g. the following:
Data1,Data2,User
abc,def,foo
hij,klm,foo
nop,qrs
tuv,wxy

In this case, I want to add bar to the end of the rows without foo. That's easily accomplished with sed '/foo/!s/$/,bar/'. The issue is that this will add a ,bar to the first line as well. I know that I can skip the first line with a 2,$ but when I do that it seems to not respect both "line number" and "negated search" instructions. Is there a way inside sed to incorporate both?
(To be clear, I know I have other options. I can probably do multiple sed operations, or I can write a simple macro in vim and be done in a second as well. But in this case, I want to see if it can be done entirely in a single sed.)

Perhaps sed '1b;/foo/!s/$/,bar/' file? This will break out of any processing on the first line.

Here is a sed command that should work with any version of sed:
sed '2,${ /foo/!s/$/,bar/; }' file

Data1,Data2,User
abc,def,foo
hij,klm,foo
nop,qrs,bar
tuv,wxy,bar

If you want to give awk a chance then it is much easier with any version of the awk:
awk 'NR > 1 && !/foo/ {$0 = $0 ",bar"} 1' file

Data1,Data2,User
abc,def,foo
hij,klm,foo
nop,qrs,bar
tuv,wxy,bar


sed is great for doing s/old/new on individual lines but for anything else just use awk. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{n=NF} NF<n{$0=$0 ",bar"} 1' file
Data1,Data2,User
abc,def,foo
hij,klm,foo
nop,qrs,bar
tuv,wxy,bar

With that you don't need to specify foo or anything else that'd tightly couple your code to your data. The script saves in a variable (n=NF) how many fields (NF) are in the first header line of input (NR==1) and if it comes across any line with fewer than that number of fields (NF<n) then it appends ,bar to the end. Then it prints every line (1 is idiomatic shorthand for {print}).

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '1!{/foo/!s/$/,bar/}' file

If it is not the first line and a line does not contain foo append ,bar.
Alternative:
sed '1b;/foo/b;s/$/,bar/' file


This will result in a second line abc,def,foo,bar though, which is not what I want.

Oops misread the question
